# issue to fetch only one column from a table in my mysql query using magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I am new in magento. I have written a code like:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_type_id'))
            ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
 ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir());

        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'))
        {
            $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'));
        }
        $pr = $products->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array('cat_product' => 'catalog_category_product'),'cat_product.product_id=e.entity_id');
        if($categoryIds != ''){
               $pr->where("cat_product.category_id IN($categoryIds)");
        }
```

which returns the following query

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `cat_product`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `cat_product` ON cat_product.product_id=e.entity_id WHERE (cat_product.category_id IN(4,11,23,16,6,7)) ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` DESC
```

though I have specified only one column `entity_type_id` from `catalog_product_entity` table.
Please let me know how to do that and where I did the mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody is there please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this way in your collection string after `where` condition

```
  $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
  $select->columns(array('category_name' => 'cname.value'));
```

For you its  like

```
$pr->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
$pr->columns(array('category_name' => 'cname.value'));
```

just set your column name with your database table name istead of `cname.value`

hope this will sure help you